# ¨USB device: card reader¨ is draining the battery even if it is not used

Tags: usb, power-management, macbook-pro, card-reader, powertop

I`ve installed Ubuntu on my MacBook Pro Retina 13 and I am trying to get the best battery life possible. I'm using PowerTop to manage what needs to be changed and pm-utils to save power.

PowerTop says that my card reader is working at 100% and is consuming between 0.8 and 2 watts. I already tried to calibrate PowerTop, but the consumption remains.

How can I freeze that card reader when I`m not using it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following command to disable the card reader on my MBP 11.1 with Ubuntu 15.04:

```
echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-3/remove
```

In case you have another MBP revision or different Ubuntu version, you may have to use another device ID.

Also, I believe that WiFi, not the card reader, is the main battery-eater, appearing to consume aroung 11-15W (powertop 2.7) even with power management enabled.

Comment: did you try something with the wifi? i asked for the card reader because is kinda strange that it appears in the top 3 of battery drainer even if i do not use it during the whole work session. to remount it should i use the same line with ¨mount¨ instead of ¨remove¨?

Comment: Just found a more proper way to disable/enable the card reader: `echo "2-3" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind`, then `echo "2-3" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found any solution for WiFi power consumption, at least for the consumption detected by PowerTOP. I only tried installing a proprietary *bcmwl* driver, but I didn't seem to help: my WiFi still consumes no less than 11W with power management on.

Comment: there should be an issue with powertop (i´m running 2.6.1 version) because wifi is consuming even if turned of, and i do not think that´s normal... maybe i´ve to re-re-re-calibrate for the tenth time

Comment: I also think that's quite possible, since it's the same for me in PowerTOP 2.7.1.

Comment: What about the original problem with the SD reader? Has my answer helped to solve it?

Comment: that line isn´t working for me... i´ve noticed that while the card reader was consuming so much at the least it was working properly. right now powertop doesn´t mention it in his list, but it isn´t working as it is supposed to! if i want to use tha card reader i can only boot with the card in...